# What is the best way to set default values to the isolated scope of a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, default, angularjs-scope

I´ve seen here a lot of different descriptions of setting the default values for the isolated scope of a directive. But what is the best way to do this and where should I do this.
Is it better in the controller or in the pre- or postlink-function?
Should I set the default-values to the attributes in the link- or compile-functions or directly to the scope?

Comment: Your question is a bit broad and difficult to answer as it sort of depends on your use case. Could you be more specific? Perhaps give an example?

Comment: Sorry, I´m looking for a general answer to this question. At the moment I´m writing a scrollbar-directive with more options than the normal scrollbar. Here I have the isolated-scope-variables orientation (vertical or horizontal), min, max, range, ... As default-values I want to have orientation='vertical', min=0, max=100, range=10 @Anders Ekdahl

Answer (score 0):

You should start your research with the AngularJS directives documentation, in particular the section about [isolating the scope of a directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive).

For my self, I prefer to use the attribut `scope` in the directive like that :

```
directive('myCustomer', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',  // Our directive must be describe as Element <myCustomer>.
    scope: {
      customerInfo: '=info'
    },
    link: function(scope, element) {
      console.log(scope.customerInfo); // Should display 'Naomi' in our example.
    }
  };
});
```

And then, initialise your directive in the HTML :

```
<my-customer info="naomi"></my-customer>
```

You tell the directive to initialise the `scope.customerInfo` with the value of the HTML attribute `info`

I don't know if it's the best way to initialise a directive, but I think it's almost a clean way.

Comment: I think you didn´t understand me. In your example I´m looking for the best way to set a default value to customerInfo which is set, when you  only type <my-customer>...</my-customer> @Noémi Salaün

Comment: Ok, I did not realize this detail. I have forked the **[documentation example](http://plnkr.co/edit/grAllAL9cFyaxE33uN2m?p=preview)**. The `scope: {}` isolate the directive scope from the controller. You can comment it to see the controller value set in the directive template.